# php convert date format Manual dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: php, date

**Use date()**

```
$sqldate = "2016-07-18";
$newDate = date("d-m-Y",$sqldate);
```

**I also use**

```
implode('-', array_reverse(explode('/', $sqldate)));
```

I am trying to convert a date from yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy (but not in SQL);
however I don't know how the date function requires a timestamp, 
and I can't get a timestamp from this string.

I am getting particular date format. WHY? I tried get a date expected format, i tried php date but no success..

**I excpected output**

```
18/07/2016
```

Comment: strtotime `date("d/m/Y",strtotime($sqldate));`

Comment: Doing improper way but logical, you did this mistake check this : https://eval.in/606740

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strtotime()`.

```
$sqldate = "2016-03-21";
echo $newDate = date("d/m/Y",  strtotime($sqldate));
```

**Output**

```
21/03/2016
```

**Live Demo : [Click Here](https://eval.in/606738)**

Answer (score 2):

```
 $sqldate = "2016-03-21";
 echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($sqldate));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sqldate = "2016-03-21";
$newDate = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($sqldate));
```

this is what you need.